# Created a Soap Webservice and calling it in asp.net uisng code and getting error of The remote name could not be resolved

Tags: asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0, soap, soapui

I had developed one web service in SOAP format and trying to access service in asp.net using the below mentioned code.

```
 public static void CallWebService()
        {
            try
            {
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

                var _url = "https://test.in/ModelDetail/Service.asmx";

                var _action = "https://test.in/ModelDetail/GetWarrantyDetails";

                XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope();
                HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, _action);
                InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);

                // begin async call to web request.
                IAsyncResult asyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null, null);

                // suspend this thread until call is complete. You might want to
                // do something usefull here like update your UI.
                asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

                // get the response from the completed web request.
                string soapResult;
                //using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
                using (HttpWebResponse webResponse= (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
                {
                    using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    Console.Write(soapResult);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex) { throw ex; }
        }

        private static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url, string action)
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            return webRequest;
        }

        private static XmlDocument CreateSoapEnvelope()
        {
            XmlDocument soapEnvelop = new XmlDocument();

            soapEnvelop.LoadXml(@"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:tem='https://ndb.bmw.in/'><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><tem:GetWarrantyDetails><tem:IP><demono>WBA3Y37070D45</demono></tem:IP></tem:GetWarrantyDetails></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>");
            return soapEnvelop;
        }

        private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
        {
            using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
            }
        }
```

but when i call this code i get error of The remote name could not be resolved.
Tried all method but get this error only.

What is missing or wrong i am doing?

Comment: Add the error trace for better clarity.

Comment: giving error in  private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
        {
            using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
            }
        }